# Cells correspond to amount of values in array (JSON, Swift 5)

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm currently fetching the [0] value in my array to a single cell, but how do I fetch all the available values in an array and correspond the amount of cells to that? These are my current structures:

```
struct SearchResponse: Codable {        
    let ResultSet: ResultSet?
}

struct ResultSet: Codable {
    let Result: [Result]?
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let name: String?

    var search_object = [SearchObject]()
    struct SearchObject {
        var name: String
    }
}
```

This is my code to fetch the data:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://test.com")! as URL,
                                  cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                  timeoutInterval: 10.0)

request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers


URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

    guard let data = data else { return }
    do {

        let obj: SearchResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(SearchResponse.self, from: data)

        let returnOne = obj.ResultSet?.Result?[0].name

        let object = SearchObject(name: returnOne ?? "No valid responses.")

        self.search_object.append(object)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.frequentlyVisited.reloadData()
        }

    } catch {

        print("ERROR: \(error)")

    }

}.resume()
```

The following code is where I'm presenting the data on my cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! Cell

    let object = search_object[indexPath.row]

    cell.responses.setTitle("\(object.name)", for: .normal)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: It looks like you accessing the first element and assigning it to `returnOne`, can you provide code for your table/collection setup?

Comment: I just added what I believe you're referencing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest using [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for your properties:

```
struct SearchResponse: Codable {
    let resultSet: ResultSet?
}

struct ResultSet: Codable {
    let result: [Result]?
}

struct SearchObject: Codable {
    var name: String
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let name: String?
    var searchObject: [SearchObject]? = []
}
```

And update [keyDecodingStrategy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2949119-keydecodingstrategy) for your `JSONDecoder()`:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

let result: SearchResponse = try decoder.decode(SearchResponse.self,
                                                from: data)

let searchObject: [SearchObject]? = result
    .resultSet?
    .result?
    .compactMap { $0.name }
    .map(SearchObject.init)

self.search_object = searchObject ?? []
```

Comment: Great! I'll resolve this after one quick question: how do I add multiple different values, such as 'name' and 'type'?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you provide an example?